# yourkit not giving string objects during memory profiling

Tags: string, memory, profile, yourkit

on trying to monitor object sizes, string objects are not shown in the profiled results.
Can anyone tell me wat is the procedure to make them shown in results....

```
public class calling extends called {
called myobj3 = new called();
called myobj4 = new called();
    public void function() {
    myobj3.d="Plz";
    myobj3.e="Help";
    myobj4.d="Thank";
    myobj4.e="You";   
    myobj3.act();
    myobj4.act();
    }
 public static void main(String [] args) { 
    System.out.println("calls an object from called.java");
    calling obj = new calling();
    obj.function();
 }
 }
class called {
public String d;
public String e;  
public void act() {
System.out.println(d+e);
}
}
```

memory profile Retained size Shallow Size
    [Unreachable] called 40 40
    [Unreachable] called 40 40

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, your objects have been collected or scheduled for collection (unreachable). In which point do you capture memory snapshot?

Disclaimer: I'm a YourKit developer.